# How to fix "An expression may not contain a dynamic operation" in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a `PUT` Request where I passed in a `json` string value that contains an ID value and the other variables and values. After which I'll `deserialize` it and find the ID from the `json` in the Database, and then update the values:

```
 var bookininput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(value);

 if (bookininput.id == null || bookininput.id == 0)
 {
     return BadRequest("no id provided");
 }
 else { 
     var log = _context.BIBOLogs.Where(input => input.Id == bookininput.id); 
 }
```

However, I'm facing issues in `.Where(input => input.Id == bookininput.id);` because it's telling me that bookininput.id is dynamic and cannot be used for lookup. Any other methods to go around it?

Comment: LINQ is just a query language that may target lists, databases and more. Which ORM are you using? What is the *actual* exception? Looks like all you need to do is to cast ` bookininput.id` to an `int` or whatever type `input.Id` is

Comment: i'm using EFCore

Comment: Using another variable of the proper class instead of `bookininput.id` should do the trick.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` in the first place? That's almost always a sign of bad code. Every time you use dynamic, a kitten dies...

Comment: If you used LINQ to Objects, ie if `BIBOLogs` was eg a `List<BIBOLog>` or `BIBOLog[]` you wouldn't get this error. You get an error in this case because EF Core doesn't know which types when it generates a SQL statement, if it needs to cast or not

Comment: +100 for the kitten dies comment

Comment: What the type of your `id` is? its `int` or `string` or any else?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a known class/type when doing your filter instead of `dynamic`. I'm assuming that the `bookininput.id` is `int` on the following example:

```
var bookininput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(value);
if (bookininput.id == null || bookininput.id == 0)
{
    return BadRequest("no id provided");
}
else 
{
    int inputId = int.Parse(bookininput.id);

    var log = _context.BIBOLogs
        .Where(input => input.Id == inputId);
}
```